# Angular 1.6.1 dynamic route template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to implement a dynamic routing solution that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989811/angularjs-how-about-multiple-routes-with-different-templates-but-the-same-contr), but it's not working.  I've adapted it for my app as follows. When troubleshooting I added an otherwise after my when and it is reached each time. I can't figure out why the dynamic route isn't being handled when I request `#/contact/list`. I'm using AngularJS 1.6.1.  Is there a different syntax for the route path when using AngularJS 1.6.1?

```
$routeProvider.
when('/:templateName/:pageId', {
    templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
        return 'views/' + urlattr.templateName + '/' + urlattr.pageId + '.html';
    },
    controller: 'contactController'
}).
otherwise({
    templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
        return 'views/home/home.html'
    },
    controller: 'homeController'
});
```

Comment: I figured it out.  My route apparently is fine.  The url I was using for testing didn't have the "!" character in it.  I should have used ""#!/contact/list" to test with.

PS - I do not have the reputation to provide the answer and close this out, so please do so for me.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the hashPrefix `!` in your route. Change your route into `#!/contact/list` instead of `#/contact/list` and you will be fine.

You could change or deactivate this prefix by using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`.

#### Hashbang mode

```
$locationProvider
    .html5Mode(false)
    .hashPrefix('!');
```

#### HTML5 Mode

```
$locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true);
```

Take a look at the [AngularJS location documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more information.